# rmarkdown normalizePath error in download

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I got the following code from https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/016-knitr-pdf however cannot get it to run on my computer. The PDF, html, and word all result in the same error - in my download window in my browser it simply says "Failed - Server problem," In my r console it gives me the following details:

```
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
 path[1]="report.Rmd": The system cannot find the file specified
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
 path[1]="report.Rmd": The system cannot find the file specified
Warning: Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute: file 'report.Rmd' does not 
exist
 [No stack trace available]
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?? I've never worked with rmarkdown, any advice is greatly appreciated!!

UI:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   title = 'Download a PDF report',
   sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
   helpText(),
  selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
              choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
  radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
               inline = TRUE),
  downloadButton('downloadReport')
),
   mainPanel(
     plotOutput('regPlot')
   )
 )
```

)

Server:

```
 server <- function(input, output) {

 regFormula <- reactive({
   as.formula(paste('mpg ~', input$x))
 })

 output$regPlot <- renderPlot({
   par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1))
   plot(regFormula(), data = mtcars, pch = 19)
 })

 output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
   filename = function() {
     paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
       input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
     ))
   },

   content = function(file) {
     src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

     # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
     # permission to the current working directory
     owd <- setwd(tempdir())
     on.exit(setwd(owd))
     file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

     library(rmarkdown)
     out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
       input$format,
       PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
     ))
     file.rename(out, file)
   }
   )

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Where have you put your file `report.Rmd`?

Comment: I have a blank report.Rmd saved onto my desktop. Do I need to specify the pathway somewhere in this? @StéphaneLaurent

Comment: Of course you need to specify the path.

Answer (score 1):

I found that placing a dummy "report.Rmd" file in my working directory allowed me to remove the cryptic error messages above.

Sadly, this generated a couple of new error messages on my terminal and it still didn't enable me to download a PDF, but it did allow me to get past the original error messages reported in the OP.